# Add custom option image to configurable drop down

Tags: magento-1.9

I Want to Show configurable product's custom option drop down with custom option image. Can you please inform me what should I do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

To Show the configurable product's custom option  as custom option image, you can use the below extension:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-1-1.html

I have used this extension before. It worked fine.
Worked for me in Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Comment: I want to show image in configurable option drop down .

Comment: Yes you can specify the images in configuration option for each option and it will pick from media folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Option Image Tooltip For Magento 2](https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/custom-option-image-tooltip-for-magento-2.html) Extension to show configurable product's custom option drop down with custom option image.

This extension allows to display image or color for select type custom options. I hope this will help you.

Thanks.